# react-native-background-timer Cannot read property 'start' of null

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to use this library in react native. https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/. When I run my function startBackgroundTask() (will include later), I am given an error `Cannot read property 'start' of null`.

Is there some way I can fix this on my end, or should I put up an issue on the repo?

This is the JS file that contains my usage of the background timer.

```
import BackgroundTimer from "react-native-background-timer";
import axios from "axios";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

const API_URL = "https://ddda.lennardf1989.com/api/v2/grace/NintendoSwitch";
// console.log("hello from backgroundapitask")

const startBackgroundTask = () => {
    // console.log('hello from inside of startbackgroundtask')
    // console.log(BackgroundTimer)
    BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
            if (response.data.grace === "yes") {
                PushNotification.localNotification({
                    title: "The Ur-Dragon Is In Grace!",
                    message: "Go get those rewards",
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data from API:", error);
        }
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000); // Run every 5 minutes
};

export default startBackgroundTask;
```

My intent is to check the API every 5 minutes and send a notification depending on the output. Pretty basic stuff, I thought.

Quick reminder of the error: `Cannot read property 'start' of null`
Since I am not trying to access 'start' myself, I assume something is happening in the library. Tried running it both in and out of a UseEffect, but I got the same error. When I run the app without running startBackgroundTask(), it runs fine. Tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling fresh, but that didn't work either. Tried instantiating BackgroundTimer, but it's a singleton. All of the commented console.logs run fine, so the problem is happening right when the code gets to runBackgroundTimer - it's not a problem with exporting/importing. If it helps, the console.log outputting BackgroundTimer shows `{"callbacks": {}, "uniqueId": 0}`.
I also tried using a non-async callback function, and using setInterval instead of runBackgroundTimer. Neither worked - the error persisted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.